# Smart way to remove rules from lists, leaving just values, specifically from FindMinimum output

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, map, rule, coding-style

I would like to know if there is a **direct way** to **remove** the **rules from a list of rules**.

I know that, simply, this can be done with:

```
 [in]  := {a,b} /. {a->1,b->2}
 [out] := {1,2}
```

But the **output from FindMinimum** returns a **list with the second element as a list of rules.** i.e.:

```
 [in]  := FindMinimum[f,x]
 [out] := {0.1234,{x->321}}
```

**Successfully**, I got rid of it the rule by using **Map** (/.)

```
 [in]  := { #[[1]], x /. #[[2]] } & @ FindMinimum[f,x]
 [out] := {0.1234,321}
```

But is there any other, more elegant, way?

*Scratch ideas of my desired output*:

Does exist a function to remove all the rules and leave behind just the values? Kind of a "RemoveRules" function

```
 [in]  := RemoveRules[ FindMinimum[f,x] ]
 [out] := {0.1234,321}
```

I've observed in more advanced coding, that `_` does "nothing" over mapped lists. Maybe like this?

```
 [in]  := {_,x} /. FindMinimum[f,x] 
 [out] := {0.1234,321}
```

Comment: The function 'Values' does not work, as all the elements of the list are not rules. (the first element is a value, the second is a rule)

Comment: This is not correct, I mean the comment you made here - see my answer to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to add this reply in response to the comment written under the OP.

> *The function [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) does not work, as all the elements of the list are not rules. (the first element is a value, the second is a rule)*

Well, it works if you [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) appropriately

```
Values @@@ FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}]
```

> [image: values]

Comment: This feels like a weird sort of hack. It was very unexpected to me. Basically we have `Values@@1 === 1`, but NOT `Values@1 === 1`, and in fact the latter emits an error. I would be uncomfortable suggesting this as a solution unless someone can show documentation or at least some semantic justification.

Comment: @lericr thanks for sharing your thoughts. I think, though, that we should be interested in `Values@@@1` which works fine as you can [`see`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyXLR.png) and not at `Values@1`. Am I confusing myself?

Comment: @lericr sorry for the double comment, but another -potentially and hopefully- useful way of understanding this is [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCvDv.png) minimal example. If you think it would make the answer more complete, I can include it.

Comment: I'm still sort of pondering this. I understand what's happening, and I understand why your solution works. What I'm pondering is whether we should be suggesting something like this, especially with Values...

Comment: @lericr yes, of course. Please, do take your time and I am happy to see any additional comments you might have. I have to run for a Skype, but I'll check in later :)

Comment: Basically, this is suggesting using an undocumented side effect of Apply. And I'm just having a hard time accepting that as an appropriate coding style.

Comment: @lericr `Apply` applied to atoms does nothing. See "Possible Issues" of the docs for `Apply`.  E.g. `Plot @@@ 1`. you could call this a documented behavior of `Apply` I suppose, but I agree that code should express intent. Since `Values` itself does not operate on numbers, I feel there is a mismatch, too.

Comment: For `f@@a`, we get `a`, and this is an undocumented (as far as I can tell) "feature" of Apply. We're saying, "oh, if you have a list, and a function you want to map-apply to that list, but only some of the values in the list are amenable to that function, well then you can just rely on the fact that Apply has this weird undocumented behavior that will effectively be a no-op for the non-amenable values.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very quickly before I go, I did not know that the way I presented my answers is against the rule of the site -for site maintenance and style of answering. I have seen a number of answers based on undocumented options and/or functions. Anyway, I am counting on your experience on this one. If you think that this answer is inappropriate I am happy to delete it. In case you don't find it inappropriate I am happy to adhere to criticism and update the answer, though it already has links to docs and the minimal examples in the comment sections.

Comment: My point about `Values@@1` versus `Values@1` is that someone might think (reasonably, I'd say), well, if `Values@1` throws an error because Values wasn't designed to work on "atomic" things, then `Values@@1` should also throw an error. But surprise, it doesn't, becuase of this weird behavior of Apply. But, as I say, I'm still mulling this. I'm currently leading toward eschewing this style, but maybe it'll grow on me.

Comment: @lericr yes, I realized what you meant after I had already posted my comment to you, which is why I added the second screenshot :) In any case, I am counting on what the more experienced will say, and I am happy to delete the answer or make it a comment under the OP.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for that pointer. I guess I'd have to say that "Applying to atomic objects that do not have subparts effectively does nothing" counts as documentation. Not sure why this feels so weird to me.

Comment: "... against the rule of the site -for site maintenance and style of answering" --- I didn't say it was against any such rule. I was talking programming style, which is a matter of personal opinion and taste, I think, on which people may differ. For instance `Plot @@@ Riffle[Range@Length@#, #] &@{{Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}}, {Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}}}` gives me a list of plots with indices riffled in front of them, but it's a very odd way to apply `Plot`, more confusing than riffling after plotting.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for clarifying this for me. It was an honest question I had whether I did something against some rules or not. Thanks a lot to you and lericr as well for the constructive comments. It was very interesting. Do you think I should updated some extra details in my answer?

Comment: @bmf I don't have a strong opinion. You might have noticed I abused `Apply` in one of the methods in my answer. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did and it made my day! Wonderful answer by the way. Very creative :)

Comment: @user1066 very nice! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also `#[[-1]]& @@@ FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}]` or `Last@@@FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}]`

Answer (score 8):

Let

```
ruleNixer = Rule[_, v_] :> v;
```

**Example1** from the docs:

```
FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}]
```

> {-3.28837, {x -> 3.42562}}

```
FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}] /. ruleNixer

{-3.28837, {3.42562}}
```

This can be flattened as needed.

**Example 2:**

```
FindMinimum[{x + y, 
   x + 2 y >= 3 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && y \[Element] Integers}, {x, 
   y}] /. ruleNixer
```

> ```
> {2., {0., 2}}
> ```

The second example clearly shows that getting rid of rules has limited usefulness. For instance, there are two variables x and y and the 0, 2 are values for those variables respectively. Removing rules removes that information too. This looks like an [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 8):

These methods work correctly with any number of variables of any dimensionality:

```
f1 = Last[#, #] & /@ Flatten@# &;
f2[{m_, r_}] := Flatten[{m, Values[r]}, 1]
```

Examples:

```
min1 = FindMinimum[{x . {1, 2, 3}, x \[Element] Sphere[]}, x]
min2 = FindMinimum[{x + y, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {-3.74166, {x -> {-0.267261, -0.534522, -0.801784}}}
>
> {-1.41422, {x -> -0.707108, y -> -0.707108}}
> ```

```
f1@min1
f1@min2
f2@min1
f2@min2
```

> ```
> {-3.74166, {-0.267261, -0.534522, -0.801784}}
>
> {-1.41422, -0.707108, -0.707108}
>
> {-3.74166, {-0.267261, -0.534522, -0.801784}}
>
> {-1.41422, -0.707108, -0.707108}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

#### Odds and ends

Single and two-variable examples:

```
out = FindMinimum[Sin[x], x]
out2 = FindMinimum[Sin[x] + Cos[y], {x, y}]
(*
{-1., {x -> -1.5708}}
{-2., {x -> -1.5708, y -> 3.14159}}
*)
```

Unflattened results (can always `Flatten[]` them):

```
out /. Rule -> (#2 &)
out2 /. Rule -> (#2 &)
Apply[#2 &, out2, {2}] (* N.B. #2& @@@ -2. yields -2. *)
Extract[out2, {{1}, {2, All, 2}}]
FoldList[Values[#2] &, out2]
(*
{-1., {-1.5708}}
{-2., {-1.5708, 3.14159}}
...
*)
```

Flattened results (works on both one- and two-variable):

```
Flatten[out2 /. Rule -> (#2 &)] (* see previous set of examples *)
Cases[out2, _?NumericQ, 3](* or Cases[out2,_Real,3] for FindMinimum *)
Extract[out2, Join[{{1}}, Table[{2, j, 2}, {j, Length@Last[out2]}]]]
FoldList[Sequence @@ Values@#2 &, out2]
Level[out2, {-1}][[;; ;; 2]]
{#, ## & @@ (#2 & @@@ #2)} & @@ out2 
(*  {-2., -1.5708, 3.14159}  *)
```

One-variable only:

```
Extract[out, {{1}, {2, 1, 2}}]
(*  {-1., -1.5708}  *)
```

See previous see for multivariable `Extract` method. Often when working in a multivariable project, I define `vars` to be the variables and use it so I don't have to type the variables out every time:

```
vars = {x, y};
out2 = FindMinimum[Sin[x] + Cos[y], vars];
Extract[out2, Join[{{1}}, Thread[{2, Range@Length@vars, 2}]]]
(*  {-2., -1.5708, 3.14159}  *)
```

Don't forget this unasked-for method of dealing with deconstructing the solution (I'd prefer to keep the independent variable solution component as replacement rules and just separate them from the optimum):

```
{ymin, xmin} = FindMinimum[Sin[x], x];
```

*Update:* Another way:

```
sol = Last@FindMinimum[f[x, y], {x, y}];
{f, x, y} /. sol (* or {x, y, f} /. sol *)
```

But I wouldn't use it if reevaluating `f` is expensive.  `FindArgMin[f, vars]` returns a "solution" but not in the standard form of replacement rules. So if you want neither the value of `f` nor a `Rule`-form solution, use

```
FindArgMin[Sin[x], x]
FindArgMin[Sin[x] + Cos[y], {x, y}];
(*  {-1.5708}  <-- N.B. a 1-vector, not a scalar *)
(*  {-1.5708, 3.14159}  *)
```

And complementarily, for the function value without the argument values, there is

```
FindMinValue[f[x], x]
```

Comment: (+1) Some of your methods with flattening won't work for multidimensional variables. For example, `Flatten[out2 /. Rule -> (#2 &)]` would be better written as `Flatten[out2 /. Rule -> (#2 &), 1]` or `Flatten[out2] /. Rule -> (#2 &)`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Might not one want a solution totally flat in any problem? Whether a two variable problem is stated in terms of `x` and `y` or a two-dimensional `x`, the solution is the same and for, say, CSV, you'd want it flat. I can also see why one might want it the way you suggest. To me, `Flatten[Reverse@out2 /. Rule -> (#2 &)]` seems a commonly found structure in which value of the dependent variable follows those of the independent. For the general problem, "to remove rules from lists." `Flatten[sol] /. ...` destroys a solution set. We have only one simple example — not much to go on.

Answer (score 7):

If you're needing to handle output from FindMinimum specifically, then since you know that structure you know how to "re-structure" it:

```
Extract[FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}], {{1}, {2, 1, 2}}]
```

or

```
MapAt[Last@*First, FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}], -1]
```

or any number of such variants.

If you're asking more generally, "how to extract the 'value' part from a Rule", then that's the same as asking, "how to extract the second part from a Rule", or equivalently, "how to extract the last part of a Rule". And so given any `ruleExpr`, you can do any of these (or any equivalent thing with related list-aware functions):

```
Last[ruleExpr]
ruleExpr[[2]]
ruleExpr[[-1]]
```

**EDIT**

Since you discovered Values, here is one way you could use that:

```
MapAt[First@*Values, FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}], -1]
```

Answer (score 3):

We could also employ a deconstructing function:

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := a
f[a : {__Rule}] := Last /@ a
```

Examples:

```
sol = FindMinimum[x Cos[x], {x, 2}]
```

{-3.28837, {x -> 3.42562}}

```
f /@ sol
```

{-3.28837, {3.42562}}

```
sol = FindMinimum[Sin[x] + Cos[y], {x, y}]
```

{-2., {x -> -1.5708, y -> 3.14159}}

```
f /@ sol
```

{-2., {-1.5708, 3.14159}}